# How can i open a network stored file using JCIFS like ES File Explorer Does?

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, jcifs

I'm working on an android app, and I can actually get a list of all my files, but can't use the URL to open a file from the list, I also tried to open from `InputStream`, but this does not work.

What I want to do is something like ES File Explorer does, I know they use JCIFS library, and that when you open a file (an MP3 for example), they make some kind of Tunnel with sockets, that reads the file and pass it to the propper app in an HTTP format.

Example:

If my nas file path is:

```
smb://My_IP_Address/SharedFolder/Media/MyMusic.mp3
```

ES File Explorer send an URL like this:

```
http:// 127.0.0.1:59777/smb%2FMy_IP_Address%2FSharedFolder%2FMedia%2FMyMusic.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I want to use comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough reputation...

What I found on ES Explore or other same app, they seemed not only use JCIFS , but also use nanoHTTPD...

They transfer the nas file to samba file, then use nanoHTTPD as a Streaming server to serve the multimedia files...

There got many sample on the web, here a discussion =>
 [How to serve a file on sdcard using NanoHTTPD (inside Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359304/how-to-serve-a-file-on-sdcard-using-nanohttpd-inside-android)

Hope this can help you...

Comment: I already solve it, but efectively, i made it using JCifs and NanoHTTPD. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's off course doable but kind of tricky. Your app must act as a server, reading an input stream from the samba share, streaming it to a third party application like a music player if we are talking about a mp3 file.

You'll find details here : [Android ServerSocket programming with jCIFS streaming files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058135/android-serversocket-programming-with-jcifs-streaming-files)