# Error with latest jar of Nanohttpd

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd

I followed the SO for setting NanoHttpd to serve files from here - [How to serve a mp3 file using latest NanoHTTPD 2.3.0 in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562616/how-to-serve-a-mp3-file-using-latest-nanohttpd-2-3-0-in-android)

This works but I require the use the latest version from Github, because it handles more HTTP methods and is required for project.

I built the jar locally and added and compiled the APK. The web server initializes but every request is returned as `Not Found`. Nothing else. There is no log for that as well to see the problem. What is going on?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Map;

import android.util.Log;

import org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.NanoHTTPD;
import org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.response.Response;
import org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.response.Status;
import org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.request.Method;

import static org.nanohttpd.protocols.http.response.Response.newChunkedResponse;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public StackOverflowMp3Server server;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        server = new StackOverflowMp3Server();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Httpd", "The server could not start.");
        }
        Log.w("Httpd", "Web server initialized.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }

    public class StackOverflowMp3Server extends NanoHTTPD {

        public StackOverflowMp3Server() {
            super(8089);
        }

        public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
                              Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters,
                              Map<String, String> files) {
            String answer = "";
            Log.w("HTTPD", uri);
            Log.w("HTTPD", parameters.toString());

            Log.w("HTTPD", "Method is: "+method.toString());
            Log.w("HTTPD", "Header is: "+header.toString());

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream("/storage/C67A-18F7/"
                        + "/Music/"+uri);
                Log.w("HTTPD", uri + " found");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newChunkedResponse(Status.OK, "audio/mpeg", fis);
        }
    }
}
```

This same code works in 2.2 till 2.3
But not in the latest, 2.3.2

I get the server started prompt in the adb logcat
    `03-26 18:18:26.005 15056 15056 W Httpd   : Web server initialized.`
But all other requests returns `Not Found`

```
>$ curl -X GET http://192.168.1.2:8089  
Not Found
>$ curl -X GET http://192.168.1.2:8089/demo.mp3  
Not Found
```

I can't find what the problem is with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `serve()` does not override any method NanoHTTPD is calling. The default implementation returns "404 Not Found".

The signature for `serve()` is

```
protected Response serve(IHTTPSession session)
```

However it's deprecated. Have a look at `IHandler`s as introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/commit/f57064fc3783889a899b2ea5374f9ea2f7a07051). (The default handler does still call the deprecated `serve()` method.)

Comment: I did add the @Override flag but Android returned, `Error:(51, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

Comment: Yes, your method has different signature (method arguments)