# How to open a HTTP server in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, http, react-native

I want to be able to send music to sonos using its API. Unfortunately the only way I know is to send an `URI` to the device so it can download it.

I have visited already the package [react-native-httpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-httpserver). This one has not been tested in Android. So I had a look over Android's [nanoHTTPD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359304/how-to-serve-a-file-on-sdcard-using-nanohttpd-inside-android) and other similar packages in iOS as [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) is.

It should not very difficult to create a wrapper over those packages to build something cross-platform but I wonder if there is another solution in Javascript or some work developing over [react-native-tcp](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, time has passed by and some packages have been released. Even with limitations, but looks promising so far:

- HTTP Static server: https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server
- Quite flexible (but Android only) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-http-server
- Limited but both platforms https://github.com/alwx/react-native-http-bridge

Comment: Thanks for this! It is so difficult to search for this and not get basic tutorials on react-native-cli.

Comment: I am now searching for one of these two things and I'm having similar trouble: Serving a webm file over one of these http servers, or starting a Websocket server. Any thoughts?

Comment: For serving files I guess I'd use HTTP Static server

Comment: I am trying to create an app that cast local files but I am unable to do that, any idea how to access local files on server using above module

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still looking for a good package to open a HTTP server in react native, `react-native-http-bridge` is unmaintained, but there is a maintained version:

- react-native-http-bridge-refurbished: https://github.com/Alwinator/react-native-http-bridge-refurbished

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `react-native-fetch-blob` https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob, I have used it to send pictures and It works very well. It supports both `ios` and `Android`